# Expected ";" before "{" token?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am still having trouble with the WebKit tutorial that I am trying from Apple's website:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/MultipleWindows.html

The .h file is as follows:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface MyDocument : NSDocument
{
IBOutlet id webView;
IBOutlet id textField;
}

- (IBAction)connectURL:(id)sender //Provides me with the error 'Expected ";" before "{" token'
{
[[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[sender stringValue]]]];
}

@end
```

Can you see anything that is wrong with that and why it is giving me a problem, please?

-- Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

Yes! you've got your implementation in your header file. Move this to your .m file:

```
- (IBAction)connectURL:(id)sender {
    [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[sender stringValue]]]];
}
```

And replace it with the method declaration:

```
- (IBAction)connectURL:(id)sender;
```

Comment: No problem! If this answers your question, would you mind hitting the check mark by my answer?

Answer (score 5):

This is an interface declaration, so you can't actually define a method there.

You need to only declare the method there, then put the definition in an `@implementation` block.

Comment: Thank you, darren and Jonathan!