# Expected ";" before { token

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expected “;” before “{” token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384097/expected-before-token)

So I'm getting the error on a piece of code copied from a book
After the interface definition there are overriding methods defined. This is where I seem to be having problems. Trying to get this code working so I can continue learning.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Sprite : NSObject{
    CGFloat x; 
    CGFloat y;
    CGFloat r;
    CGFloat g;
    CGFloat b;
    CGFloat alpha; //alpha value, for transparency
    CGFloat speed; //speed of movement in pixels/frame
    CGFloat angle; //angle of movement in degrees
    CGFloat rotation; //rotation of our sprite in degrees about the center
    CGFloat width;
    CGFloat height;
    CGFloat scale; //uniform scaling factor for size
    int frame; //for animation

    CGFloat cosTheta; //precomputed for speed
    CGFloat sinTheta;
    CGRect box; //our bounding box

    BOOL render; //true when we're rendering
    BOOL offScreen; //true when we're off the screen
    BOOL wrap; //true if you want the motion to wrap the screen
}

@property (assign) BOOL wrap, render, offScreen;
@property (assign) CGFloat x, y, r, g, b, alpha;
@property (assign) CGFloat speed, angle, rotation;
@property (assign) CGFloat width, height, scale;
@property (assign) CGRect box;
@property (assign) int frame; 

// THIS IS WHERE I'M GETTING THE ERROR
- (void) setRotation: (CGFloat) degrees 
{
    rotation = degrees * 3.141592 / 180.0;
}

-(CGFloat) rotation
{
    return rotation*180.0/3.141592;
}

- (void) setAngle: (CGFloat) degrees
{
    angle = degrees*3.141592/180.0;
    cosTheta = cos(angle);
    sinTheta = sin(angle);
}

- (CGFloat) angle
{ 
    return  angle*180.0/3.141592; 
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this all in the same file? You should only declare your method *signatures* in the .h file, and the detail in the implementation section.

So, your .h file would be as it is, except instead of the method details, you just end each signature with a semicolon:

```
- (void) setRotation: (CGFloat) degrees; 
- (CGFloat) rotation;
- (void) setAngle: (CGFloat) degrees;
- (CGFloat) angle;
```

And put the actual implementation in your .m file.

Answer (score 1):

An interface only contains the prototypes of the methods, not their contents.

You need a separate `@implementation` for that.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing @end in .h file, that's why you receive Expected ; before token

Also if you don't declare methods in .h file they are private to that class.

So create .h file with this contents

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Sprite : NSObject{
    CGFloat x; 
    CGFloat y;
    CGFloat r;
    CGFloat g;
    CGFloat b;
    CGFloat alpha; //alpha value, for transparency
    CGFloat speed; //speed of movement in pixels/frame
    CGFloat angle; //angle of movement in degrees
    CGFloat rotation; //rotation of our sprite in degrees about the center
    CGFloat width;
    CGFloat height;
    CGFloat scale; //uniform scaling factor for size
    int frame; //for animation

    CGFloat cosTheta; //precomputed for speed
    CGFloat sinTheta;
    CGRect box; //our bounding box

    BOOL render; //true when we're rendering
    BOOL offScreen; //true when we're off the screen
    BOOL wrap; //true if you want the motion to wrap the screen
}

@property (assign) BOOL wrap, render, offScreen;
@property (assign) CGFloat x, y, r, g, b, alpha;
@property (assign) CGFloat speed, angle, rotation;
@property (assign) CGFloat width, height, scale;
@property (assign) CGRect box;
@property (assign) int frame; 

- (void) setRotation: (CGFloat) degrees; 
- (CGFloat) rotation;
- (void) setAngle: (CGFloat) degrees;
- (CGFloat) angle;

 @end
```

And then in .m file this

```
#import "Sprite.h"

@implementation Sprite

- (void) setRotation: (CGFloat) degrees 
{
    rotation = degrees * 3.141592 / 180.0;
}

-(CGFloat) rotation
{
    return rotation*180.0/3.141592;
}
- (void) setAngle: (CGFloat) degrees
{
    angle = degrees*3.141592/180.0;
    cosTheta = cos(angle);
    sinTheta = sin(angle);
}

- (CGFloat) angle
{ 
    return  angle*180.0/3.141592; 
}

@end
```

Answer (score -3):

Just a guess, but try putting a semi-colon in like this:

```
BOOL render; //true when we're rendering
BOOL offScreen; //true when we're off the screen
BOOL wrap; //true if you want the motion to wrap the screen
};
```